# Can I use TagHelper in ASP.NET Web Aplication (.Net Framework)?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Can I use TagHelper in project ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework)?

I use VS 2017 and reference NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`. In `Views\_ViewStart.cshtml` add line `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` but I get `Error  CS0103  The name 'addTagHelper' does not exist in the current context`.
Template project which I use is MVC.

When I create project ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) everything works good.

Does TagHelpers are restricted to Core projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tag helpers is a new feature introduced in **ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0** (earlier called as MVC 6) to prove readability of razor code.
Tag Helpers enable server-side code to participate in creating and rendering HTML elements in Razor files.

As you can see, we need to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` NuGet package to enable tag helpers in ASP.NET Core application. This package is not compatiable ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework). Hence, to use tag helpers select one of the **ASP.NET Core application** template visual studio.

For more information, refer official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro).

Comment: Note: You don't need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` package to enable tag helpers. That package is simply the Mvc TagHelpers. You can  write your own in a class library by having a dependency on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime`.

Comment: That's pretty nice, also very helpful thanks for including that.